# $U(st)$ is isomorphic to $U(s)\oplus U(t)$ where $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime.Show that $U(st)$ is isomorphic to $U(s)\oplus U(t)$.

I want to show that $\phi$ :$U(st)$ $\rightarrow$ $U(s)\oplus U(t)$ defined by $\phi(x)=(x\bmod s,x\bmod t)$ is an isomorphism.

(1) Obviously $\phi$ is well defined.

(2) $\phi$ is one-one beacuse $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ yields $x \equiv y$ mod $s$ and $x \equiv y \mod t$. Thus $x \equiv y \mod st$ since $\gcd(s,t)=1$

(3) How to show $\phi$ is onto?

(4)$\phi$ is operation preserving is also trivial.

We define $U(n)$ to be the set of all positive integers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$ with the operation  multiplication modulo n

Comment: What is $U$ here?

Comment: I added the definition @Hamed

Comment: @Hamed it denotes the group of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ (the $U$ stands for units)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach one:

In this approach we directly show it is surjective. Given $(x,y)\in U(s)\times U(t)$. Consider $\phi(xt T+ys S)$ where $tT\equiv1~mod~(s),~sS\equiv1~mod~(t)$. Why does such $S,~T$ exists? Why is $xt T+ys S$ relative prime to $st$? What is $\phi(xt T+ys S)$?

Approach two:

In this approach we assume we know the fact that Euler phi function satisfies
$$\varphi(st)=\varphi(s)\varphi(t)$$
, say by method of elementary number theory. Hence the cardinality of $U(st)$ and $U(s)\times U(t)$ are same.

$U(st),~U(s)\times U(t)$: these are finite sets. Now you have a injective function between two finite sets. If these two finite sets have same cardinality, then by set theory, this injection is not only an injection but also a what?

Final remark:

Approach one gives a proof that $$\varphi(st)=\varphi(s)\varphi(t)$$ for relatively prime $s,t$.